# How can I run the alarm in the background in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I set the alarm time to 1 hour. When the application is in the running mode, the alarm is working fine but when it is in the background the alarm is not working properly. How is it possible to run the alarm in the background.

Comment: You should use local notification.

Comment: @Ishu i already use the local notification but the notification alarm tone is ringing only 30 sec i want to expand that alarm ton

Answer (score 2):

You need to use local notifications.  It's very simple.  See this document for more information (Push Notifications are from remote sources, so you can ignore them).

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1

Comment: i have already used the local notification but the alarm ring only for 30 second i want to extend the ringing time for 1 minute

Comment: thanx for suggestion but i want different way to ringing the alarm,i don't want to use local notification:)

Comment: i saw the alarm app on iTunes that is working fine in background how they did in that app?

Comment: @JaspreetSingh please give me link which alarm clock working in background.pls sent them.thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code is just show the localNotification with alert and sound in background.
So, some changes in code and use in alarm apps.

```
- (IBAction)Alert:(id)sender{

    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    //NSDate *date = [NSDate date];


    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotif.fireDate =[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Emergency";

    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
    localNotif.soundName = @"police.mp3";
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSYearCalendarUnit;


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];



}
```

Comment: thanx i already use that way but i want different to run the alarm continuously local notification tone is ringing only for 30 sec